# How to print value form qml to consol.log in blackberry 10 cascade programming?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10

I am trying the below code

`var strImage;
strImage ="cell_Image.png";
console.log("strImage" +strImage);
console.log("strImage" +2);`

Please help me......

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Got to "Other debugging techniques" in this doc:
http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/documentation/getting_started/tools/debugging.html

Or connect in ssh to your BB10 (there is a view for that in Momentics that'll autologin) and use the command "slog2info -w  "

Answer (score 1):

If console.log() in QML and qDebug<< in CPP are not printing messages in console the use the following method in your main.cpp class

```
void myMessageOutput(QtMsgType type, const char* msg){
                fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", msg);                
                fflush(stdout);
}
```

and the in main function use  "qInstallMsgHandler(myMessageOutput);" like the following

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Application app(argc, argv);
    qInstallMsgHandler(myMessageOutput);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Console logging and qDebug() output debug messages to the console only when the myMessageOutput() function is declared and registered. You should remove this code when the app is ready for release.
[You can register this handler function with qDebug by calling the qInstallMsgHandler() function in your main function after the default Application is created.](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/dev/tools/debugging_techniques.html#pat1389209067905)